# How to find the number of rows that have date time fields between 5 and 6 PM

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, date-time, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a phone log that I want to report some data off of. All of the solutions out there that I have looked up seem to assume I only have a time value and that they don't include an actual date.

I have a bunch of dates like this:

- 2/1/16 3:39 AM
- 2/1/16 10:06 AM
- 2/1/16 10:27 AM
- 2/1/16 10:34 AM
- 2/1/16 10:38 AM

Except I have around 1200 phone calls. (1288 rows total)

I want to know how many phone calls we have received between 5PM and 6PM.

So far I have tried the following and none of them worked:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C1288,">="&B1,C2:C1288,"<="&B2)

=COUNTIF(C2:C1288,">=17:00:00")-COUNTIF(C2:C1288,">18:00:00")

=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C1288>=TIME(17,0,0))*(C2:C1288 <=TIME(18,0,0)))
```

Bonus points if you can also help me group phone numbers to tell me how many rows contain the same numbers. (5555555555 has 3 rows)(4444444444 has 2 rows)

- 5555555555
- 4444444444
- 3333333333
- 6666666666
- 5555555555
- 8888888888
- 5555555555
- 4444444444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with this, assuming the entire column is date values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(A1:A10)>=17)*(HOUR(A1:A10)<=18))
```

If you need to exclude 17:00 and 18:00 then

```
=SUMPRODUCT((60*HOUR(A1:A10)+MINUTE(A1:A10)>1020)*(60*HOUR(A1:A10)+MINUTE(A1:A10)<1080))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your first part

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD($C$2:$C$1288,1)>=17/24)*(MOD($C$2:$C$1288,1)<=18/24))
```

For the second part - a pivot table would very easily group your numbers and tell you how many of each have occurred